# how to display different menu according to postid?

Tags: menus

I am searching for a way to display a different menu according to postID:

ex:

```
if ($post->ID == 2309) {
   displayMenu("menu2");
}
```

I am using Avada and looked into header.php with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_nav_menu($args)` to display different menus. Just pass menu ID, slug, name or object as `$args['menu']` parameter.

```
if ( $post->ID == 2309 ) {
  $args = array(
    'menu' => 'some-menu'
  );
  wp_nav_menu($args);
}
```

There are also other available parameters that you can pass to the function, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/